# get jquery link from variable and pass to iframe src

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I'm new to jQuery and i have a question. I'm working on a themeswitcher template. Basically, what it does: the user clicks the name of the template and bellow, in the iframe it loads the template.
The link for the demo site is this one : http://demo.pingusol.com . The problem is that when i click on the name of the template nothing shows. 
The iframe link in the html is this one :

```
<iframe id="templateframe" class="templateframecontainer" name="templateframe" src=<?     $_GET['template']?>  style="width: 100%; height: 535px;"></iframe>
```

A model of what i want to achieve is found on http://demo.hotjoomlatemplates.com 
Any help is apreciated.
Thank you.

Edit : Updated the code and now it works. But if i want to show an active template in the first page ?
The iframe code looks like so : `<iframe id="templateframe" class="changeIframe" name="templateframe" src="<? echo $_GET['template']?>"  style="width: 100%; height: 535px;"></iframe>`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The desired behavior is : when i click the link i want to see the site in the iframe. I have said that and had refference the site where you can see what is the desired achievment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("a.changeIframe").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link=$(this).attr('href');
    $("#templateframe").src(link);
}`

add the class changeIframe to the links you want to change the iframe src

you miss something
`src=<?= $_GET['template']?>`
it doesn't echo , but for your desire behaviour put this

```
src=<?= (isset($_GET['template']) and $_GET['template']!='')?$_GET['template']:'default_page.php'?>
```

Comment: Added the class in the themeswitcher.js and nothing happened.
This is in the themeswitcher.js : $(this).append(button);
 $('body').append(switcherpane);
 switcherpane.hide();
 if( $.cookie(options.cookieName) || options.loadTheme ){
  var changeIframe = $.cookie(options.cookieName) || options.loadTheme;
  switcherpane.find('a:contains('+ changeIframe +')').trigger('click');
 }

 return this;

And in the var : var switcherpane = $('<div class="jquery-ui-themeswitcher"><div id="themeGallery"><ul><li><a href="http://demo.pingusol.com/index.php?template=bakery" class="changeIframe">

Comment: did you need something else, or you get your answer .

PS: Sorry for my english, it's not my native language

Comment: Done. I have forgot to add the echo statement at the echo $_GET['template'] snipet. So the code snipet above is very good and you can see the result here : http://demo.pingusol.com . 
Thank you for your help

Comment: It`s exactly what i need. Updated the code and now is working. Thank You. And if i want to show a page in the iframe when i access the site ? Before i click select template i mean.

Comment: in the iframe the attribute put the src attribute
`src="put the url here" ` by default

Comment: but in the iframe scr i have the $get variable.

Comment: and that's not the page u are looking to put there? if is not, why put it?, also you can simply  $("#templateframe").src("ThePageYouWantToShow.html");

Comment: If u go directly to the page ,you can see the switcher up and nothing else on the page. If you select the template then you go to the other page.I wanted to display at  demo.pingusol.com the first template, meaning demo.pingusol.com/index.php?template=bakery . updated the code but with no luck

Comment: added the code but nothing happened. I will make a redirect from cpanel ...no problem. Thank you.